# Does Garageband update with High Sierra updates

Tags: macos, high-sierra, upgrade, garageband

I am running `Mavericks` om my Mac and using `Garageband` 10.1.2 .

I want to update my computer to MacOS `High Sierra`, but I do not want to change my `Garageband` version

Does `Garageband` get updated along with the `High Sierra` update of `MacOS`?

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are currently running?

Comment: Mavericks mac osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could see in the HighSierra installer there is no Garageband included in the apps list.
No guarantee, I did not try this:
You could download Garageband before the OS upgrade (in the Purchased list in Appstore), back it up. 
Then "uninstall the actual Garageband in the Applications folder
Then download the HighSierra installer (Appstore Featured).
After updating to HighSierra it should not be there. 
Then you install the backed up Garageband, I am not sure that it will install, but I suppose it does. Then try and see if it runs correctly, do not update.

Comment: That is a lot of "I did not try this" and "I am not sure" and "I suppose."

Comment: I really did it, but that Mavericks is a long time ago.. It is still in my "purchased" column. I am now on High Sierra.